# What does the term "relay competent" mean?

Tags: microbiology, terminology

I was reading the article of [Dallon & Othmer (2010)](http://www.math.umn.edu/~othmer/papers/Dallon:1997:DCM.pdf) which deals with cell aggregation in *Dictyostelium discoideum*. In the introduction of the paper it is said that cells becomes "**relay competent**". I googled for the term but could not find a good explanation for it.

> After a period of starvation they become chemotactically sensitive to cyclic adenosine 3 , 5- monophosphate (cAMP), as well as relay competent.

Can someone help me understand this term?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you read the lines immediately following your quoted line (on p.391, left column, last paragraph in the linked article) it becomes clear what **relay competent** means (and I quote):

> As a result, the cells sense and move toward a source of cAMP, and they **relay the signal as well by secreting cAMP**. [..] After about 8 h of starvation randomly located cells, called pacemakers, begin to emit cAMP periodically (Raman et al. 1976), the chemotactically competent cells move toward these pacemakers, and eventually the entire population forms a mound-shaped aggregate of up to 105 cells.

In other words, starvation makes cells move toward cAMP by chemotaxis, and  makes them **secrete cAMP** as well, which factually **relays** the cAMP signal back to other cells that are also attracted to cAMP due to starvation.